# If $|$ker $\phi| = n$, then $\phi$ is an $n$-to-$1$ maping from $G$ onto $\phi(G).$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $\phi$ be a homomorphism from $G$ to $G'$.

If $|$ker $\phi| = n$, then $\phi$ is an $n$-to-$1$ maping from $G$ onto $\phi(G).$

The book I'm reading says that this follows from the fact that:  If $\phi(g) = g'$, then $\phi^{-1}(g') = \{x \in G : \phi(x) = g'\} = gKer \phi$, and the fact that Ker$\phi = \phi^{-1}(e)$ have the same number of elements.

I can't see how this follows from these facts.  I can see how it's onto because a mapping of a set is always onto its image set, but the $n$-to-$1$ part I can't figure out.

Answer (score 1):

Given any $g'\in G'$, your book has said that the inverse image of it is *exactly* $g\ker\phi$ where $g$ is an arbitrary elements that gets mapped to $g'$. Now how many elements does it have? (The left translation by $g$ is an isomorphism).

PS: maybe you need to think this for a while: how is $\phi^{-1}(g')$ given this way *unique*?

Answer (score 0):

It follows from the fact that $\phi$ is an homomorphism:

indeed if $g$ is a preimage of $g'$ then so is $g\ker \phi$ as for any $G\in \ker \phi$

$$\phi(gG)=\phi(g)\phi(G)=\phi(g).$$
Of course any preimage must be of this form as for any two preimages $g,g'$, $g'g^{-1}\in\ker \phi$ i.e. $g'\in g\ker \phi$.

Thus any preimage has cardinality $n$, i.e. the map is $n$-to-$1$

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $\;\ker\phi=\{a_1=e,a_2,...,a_n\}\;$ and that $\;\phi(g)=w\in\phi(G)\;$ , then for all $\;1\le i\le n\;$ :

$$\phi(ga_i)=\phi(g)\phi(a_i)=\phi(g)\cdot e'=w\cdot e'=w$$

Moreover, suppose

$$\phi(h)=w\implies e'=ww^{-1}=\phi(h)\phi(g)^{-1}=\phi(h)\phi(g^{-1})=\phi(hg^{-1})\implies$$

$$hg^{-1}\in\ker\phi\implies hg^{-1}=a_k\;,\;\;\text{for some}\;\;k=1,2,...,n\implies h=a_kg$$